# How do you detect hovering over a particle in a particle system in three.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, three.js

I am trying to detect when the mouse hovers over a particle in my particle system.  The detection I was doing goes like this and is run on every frame:

```
function check_intersections() {
    var vect = new THREE.Vector3(
         mouse.x,
         mouse.y,
        0.5
    );
    projectr.unprojectVector( vect, camera );

     var raycaster = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vect.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );
     var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( particleSystem ); 

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        //intersects[ 0 ].object.materials[ 0 ].color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
        noticeDiv.text('Intersection');

    }
}`
```

The var particleSystem is my particle system with several thousand particles in it and mouse is defined whenever it moves like:

```
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {  
    // update the mouse variable
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}
```

Ive looked at several examples but cant seem to get this one right.

Comment: You should accept the correct answer below.

Answer (score 3):

`Raycaster.intersectObjects( objects )` works for an array of `THREE.Particle`s, but not for a `particleSystem`.

For an example of it's use in `CanvasRenderer`, see [this example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_particles.html).

`WebGLRenderer` does not support `THREE.Particle.

Also, have a look at `Raycaster.js` so you understand how it works.

three.js r.54

Comment: What is the difference in performance between particle system and using individual particles?  My system has about 3k stationary particles and I was wondering if this is too much to just make a particle for each one, but I realized I dont know anything about the performance I was just assuming it would be worse.

Comment: You will have to experiment. WebGLRender will have the best performance. Please remember to "accept" answers by clicking on the check mark. If you have further questions, please make a new post. Thank you.